# Fantasy novel. Young girl arrives in a fantasy world, thrown in jail and escapes by covering herself in excrement

Tags: story-identification, novel

I'm looking for a fantasy book I read around 2003-2006. But It was in France in a little library so the book might be older. It is a book for 12-16 old.

The principal character is a girl who arrived in another world, I think there was some fantasy classic creatures like orcs.
She was captured on the road because she was running from something or someone I can't remember.

After that she was put in jail. She had a girl with her in the cell. She managed to escape by covering her with excrement (I don't know how she was capable to do that but I think she did).

Comment: Was it in French, or another language?

Comment: I read it in French